# C# Vim.VMWare - Add from inventory

Tags: c#, vim, vmware

Using the VMware.Vim library on C#, I'm trying add VM back to inventory (In VMWare usually done by right clicking .vmx file, and selecting "Add to Inventory").

I already found how to remove VM from Inventory ("UnregisterVM()"), how to add to inventory from power shell ("New-VM -VMFilePath $VMXFile -VMHost $ESXHost -Location $VMFolder"), but I could not find how to do it using C# & VMware.Vim.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find it.

In VMware.Vim, under "Folder" class, there is "RegisterVM_Task" function.

VMware documentaion:  https://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.Folder.html#registerVm

My implantation (I'm sure it's not perfect and I would love be corrected if needed):

```
public void AddVMToInventory(string vmxFilePath, string vmName, string hostName, string resourcePoolName, string folderName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Filter host per host name/IP
            var hostFilter = new NameValueCollection { { "name", hostName } };
            HostSystem host = ((HostSystem)m_client.FindEntityView(typeof(HostSystem), null, hostFilter, null));
            var hostMoRef = ((HostSystem)m_client.FindEntityView(typeof(HostSystem), null, hostFilter, null)).MoRef;

            // Filter resource pool per resource pool name and host
            var poolFilter = new NameValueCollection { { "name", resourcePoolName }, { "parent", host.Parent.Value } };
            var poolMoRef = ((ResourcePool)m_client.FindEntityView(typeof(ResourcePool), null, poolFilter, null)).MoRef;

            // Filter folder per EXACT name
            var folderFilter = new NameValueCollection { { "name", "^" + folderName + "$" } };
            var folder = (Folder)m_client.FindEntityView(typeof(Folder), null, folderFilter, null);

            folder.RegisterVM_Task(vmxFilePath, vmName, false, poolMoRef, hostMoRef);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Adding VM {0} to host {1} failed due to {2}", vmName, hostName, ex));
        }
```